# Copying contents of cell in Google Sheets with IF statement

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google spreadsheet which contains the names and email addresses of faculty members at my school. I am looking to be able to have the spreadsheet create a list faculty members that I choose. I have created a column with a simple drop down list (Yes or No) and would like to know if there is an IF statement, or some other command I could use which would do the following 'if any of the drop downs are toggled to 'Yes' then copy the email address in those rows to a single cell all separated by  a semi colon' 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:H2:

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(IF(B2:B10="yes",F2:F10&";","")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use QUERY to filter a range and to return one column, then use JOIN to create a string with the results of QUERY:

```
=JOIN(";",QUERY(A2:F,"select F where B = 'Yes'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In J2 please try:

```
=if(B2="Yes",F2&";","")
```

Comment: pnuts, thanks for the response, but if I put a yes in all three columns, will this command put three email addresses in J2?